# Brackets around if and for

Tags: python

I am a python newbie and have a question. Why can a if allow a brackets and not for.

1. `if (1==2):`
2. `for (i in range(1,10)):`
3. `while (i<10):`

First one and third one are valid syntax but not second one.

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    for (i in range(1,10)):
                          ^
```

Comment: I think he wants to know *why* the second statement isn't valid.

Comment: You could do `for i in (range(1, 10)):` but it's better not to use unnecessary parens in statements like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `for (i in range(1,10))` isn't syntactically correct.

Lets assume `(i in range(1,10))` was parsed anyway, it would return a boolean. So then you're trying to say `for True` or `for False`, and booleans can't be iterated, and it's invalid syntax.

---

The reason why your other examples work is because they expect a boolean, which is what is returned from `1 == 2` and `i < 10`

Comment: `(And even then, i isn't yet defined)`...That was just an example I guess. He can define it anywhere above.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Hence the "and even then" ;)

Comment: The answer is correct, but that statement seems irrelevant. So I thought of mentioning. ;)

Comment: yes it was a example but what do you mean by even this, i is not defined

Comment: The (i in range(1,10)) is parsed first and returns a boolean.... How it is parsed when it is not a valid syntax?

Answer (score 1):

- `if` expects a value (`True` of `False`). You can put parenthesis around any values: `(1) + (1)`
- `for VAR in LIST` is a fixed syntax which does not expect a value single value, but rather **two** inputs:

  - a variable name
  - what you will iterate over

  So why would the Python language allow extra parenthesis there?

As someone had pointed on a now deleted answer (why?), this is the syntax for the `for` statement: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement :

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```